# Azure AD B2C Logint From Maui; IdentityClient returns null

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c, maui

I am trying to create a login system from my maui app with the help of azure ad b2c.

I set up this code:

```cs
private async void TestAuth2() {
  var authService = new AuthService(); // most likely you will inject it in the constructor, but for simplicity let's initialize it here
  try {

    IdentityClient = PublicClientApplicationBuilder.Create(Constants.ClientId).WithB2CAuthority(Constants.AuthoritySignIn).WithRedirectUri($"msal{Constants.ClientId}://auth").WithIosKeychainSecurityGroup("com.microsoft.adalcache").Build();

    AuthenticationResult result;
    try {
      var res = await IdentityClient.AcquireTokenInteractive(Constants.Scopes).WithPrompt(Prompt.ForceLogin).ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken.None);

      var token = res ? .IdToken; // you can also get AccessToken if you need it
      if (token != null) {
        var handler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
        var data = handler.ReadJwtToken(token);
        var claims = data.Claims.ToList();
        if (data != null) {
          var stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
          stringBuilder.AppendLine($"Name: {data.Claims.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Type.Equals("
            name "))?.Value}");
          stringBuilder.AppendLine($"Email: {data.Claims.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Type.Equals("
            preferred_username "))?.Value}");
        }
      }
    } catch (Exception e) {

    }
  } catch (MsalClientException e) {

  }
}
```

But as soon as I try to ExecuteAsync() the IdentiyClient, the app crashes with a null reference.

I have also noticed, that the Authory URL when called in a browser gives back:

The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.

But Im no sure, if that is correct or actually the error.
Is the URI Maybe wrong?

Any help would be appreciated!

[image]